# Erro no pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Bom dia pessoal,

Em "file>settings>project: ... > project interpreter" tenmho configurado o ambiente: "/home/brito/projetos/venv/saj_projects/bin/python"

E estou vivenciando o seguinte erro no pycharm:

```
/home/brito/projetos/venv/saj_projects/bin/python /home/brito/projetos/saj_projects/exemplos/me/impressao_tratamento.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/brito/projetos/saj_projects/exemplos/me/impressao_tratamento.py", line 16, in <module>
    from incolumepy.utils.files import realfilename
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'incolumepy.utils'
```

E no ambiente

```
$ source ~/projetos/venv/saj_projects/bin/activate

(saj_projects) $ pip freeze
...
idna==2.7
incolumepy.utils==0.9.3
jdcal==1.4
kiwisolver==1.0.1
...
```

Ao executar o python do ambiente diretamente fora do pycharm:

```
(saj_projects)$ python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jul 10 2018, 10:36:19) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> from incolumepy.utils.files import realfilename
>>> dir()
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'realfilename']
```

**Como proceder para corrigir a configuração do pycharm?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução. Segue:

No menu principal:

- Run > Edit Configurations...

Na janela que se abre, a esquerda selecione o projeto problemático... a direita selecione a subaba(orelha) **Configuration**.

No subtópico **Enviroment**, haverá duas opções: **"add content root to PATHOPATH"** e **"add source root to PYTHONPATH"**

- Mantenha selecionada apenas **"add content root to PATHOPATH"**